# IN predicates for non-primary key in cassandra

Tags: node.js, cassandra, express-cassandra

I'm executing following query through cqlsh.

```
select id,user_id,company_id from feed_by_user where feed_Status='active' and company_id=9592996b-495e-4b91-b29c-8c8b6213fbce and user_id in (ca7c7b34-a0e4-4dc8-a4f7-6bb249bcc0cd) allow filtering;
```

To which I'm getting expected output.

While trying to execute same query using node.js and express-cassandra driver, I'm getting:

```
IN predicates on non-primary-key columns (user_id) is not yet supported
```

My node.js code is as follows:

```
Cassandra.instance.FeedByUser.find({
    feed_status: 'active',
    company_id: company_id,
    user_id: { '$in': user_ids }
},
    { raw: true, allow_filtering: true },
    (err, feed) => {
        console.log("err >>> : ", err)
        if (err) {
            logger.error(METHOD_NAME, "Error while fetching active feed data from db")
            return callback(false)
        } else {
            logger.info(METHOD_NAME + " : executed in " + (new Date() - startTime) + "ms")
            return callback(null, feed)
        }
    })
```

Is this issue with driver I'm using, or is there any workaround to get this query executed?

Comment: Well, using `ALLOW FILTERING` in a query is an issue.  What does your PRIMARY KEY definition look like?

Comment: primary key is id, and other fields are indexes.

Comment: So, you don't even know what your primary key is?

Comment: I had designed the table schema, so I'm very much aware about keys and indexes.

Comment: As table is having too many fields, that's why I gave short answer.